# if value is not present Append Cookies in php

Tags: php, cookies

> Append value  Cookies if value is not present
>   I am trying to insert cookie logic is simple
>
> check if the value is present . if not insert new value along  with  old value in comma
>   seperated form . i have tried some code but,unable to get correct
>   result
>   -in this code a new value should be inserted,which is hapening but not getting old value

```
$current_value = '';
 if(!isset($_COOKIE['blog_id_cookie'])){
     setcookie('blog_id_cookie', $id);
     $current_value[] = $_COOKIE['blog_id_cookie'];
 } else {
     $current_value = explode(',', $_COOKIE['blog_id_cookie']);
 } 
 if(!in_array($id, $current_value)){
     $current_value[] = $id;
     $cookie_name  = "blog_id_cookie";
     setcookie($cookie_name, implode(',', $current_value));
 }
```

**> edited 2**

```
 public function Details($id,$uid){
        $cookie_name = 'blog_id_cookie';

if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
  $current_value = explode(',', $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
} else {
  $current_value = array();
}

if (!in_array($id, $current_value)) {
  $current_value[] = $id;
  setcookie($cookie_name, implode(',', $current_value));
}
}
```

Comment: in the last line it should be `$current_value`... `e` is missing there...

Comment: I  have it was mistake but still not getting exat result

Comment: first you are defining the `$current_value` variable as a `string`.. and than you are using it as an `array`.. your first line should be `$current_value = array()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are setting $current_value to a string '' but then using array syntax to add a new element. You should be setting $current_value to array() in the beginning instead.

Also you have a typo at the second setcookie() call "$current_valu" which should be "$current_value".

Here is a bit improved version of the code (in my opinion). Haven't tested this though.

```
$cookie_name = 'blog_id_cookie';

if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
  $current_value = explode(',', $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
} else {
  $current_value = array();
}

if (!in_array($id, $current_value)) {
  $current_value[] = $id;
  setcookie($cookie_name, implode(',', $current_value));
}
```

Edit: As the original post was updated with a function definition here is a comment about that. You define a function Details() but it does not return a value. What should the function do? Maybe it should `return $current_value;` or `return implode(',', $current_value);`? Also the $uid parameter seems to be unused so it could be removed.

Comment: not getting previous value along with new value only getting new value

Comment: Do you mean the old value (comma separated list) isn't preserved in the cookie and it just contains the new $id only when using this code? Or are you trying to use the $current_value at some later point in the same script but don't see the old value in it?

Comment: yes ,i want the value which was saved in cookie before along with new value in comma seperated manner

Comment: I tested this code (my version above) and it seems to work fine. Do you have some other additional code which may be the problem?

Comment: After this code has been run all the values (new and old) are in the array $current_value which you can get as comma separated string using `implode(',', $current_value)` in the same way as it is set to the cookie.

Comment: Please show the code where you are trying to read/use the values if you still have a problem.

Comment: Be aware that you can't access a new cookie set with setcookie() in the same script (during the current script execution) through $_COOKIE as $_COOKIE doesn't get updated during a PHP script. It only updates on the next page load. Only on the next page load you will have the updated cookie available in $_COOKIE so here you need to use $current_value if you need the new value later in the same script.

Comment: How are you trying to use function Details. Where do you check current_value. Since, details function does not return anything

Comment: it is  mvc pattern  where Details is the method in controller when Details() executed details page appears

Comment: Controller should not return any thing only model return

Comment: Okay, but where do you check the value of $current_value which you say only contains new value

Comment: Then controller should probably modify the model so it knows what to output. Now you are only modifying a cookie which can not be read in the model during the same page load (as I tried to explain in a comment above). So in the controller you probably need to modify some variable or object that is directly accessible to the model. Or make the controller return the value to the model as a function return value.